# ServicedComponent not being disposed in finaliser

Tags: c#, c++, com+

Questions needing answers :

1. Does the finalizer of the client side ServicedComponent call ServicedComponent.DisposeObject or Dispose?
2. How *should* destruction (release of memory) occur in the com server in relation to its usage in the client?
3. Basically - we are reaching a 2 gig limit on process size (memory) of the COM server as memory is not being released - is the solution to call explicitly call Dispose or use the using statement in the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely be calling either `Dispose` or  `ServicedComponent.DisposeObject` on the client side.  Microsoft says ["It is preferable to use the Dispose  design pattern rather than DisposeObject."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.servicedcomponent.disposeobject.aspx)

Exactly what is happening in COM+ will depend on a few things:

- Is the application a Library or Server application
- Is object pooling being used
- Is JIT being used

If the calls are out of process then it is possible that lease times may come into play.  [Understanding Enterprise Services (COM+) in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973847.aspx) is one of the best COM+ articles I've read but, since it was written in 2002, I wonder if it is still 100% accurate.